# Can Mesh detect an intersection with an object based of its domain axis instead of range axis?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

This code (from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162224/125))

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, x0, a, n0, c], {x, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-2, 4}}Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{1, -1}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Blue, Red}, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
  Prolog -> {EdgeForm[{LightBlue, Thick}], Opacity[0.5], LightBlue, 
    Rectangle[{0, -1}, {3, 1}]}], 
{{x0, 1.5}, 0, 10}, {{a, -.3}, -1, 1}, {{n0, 1.1}, 1, 2}, {{c, 0.1}, 0.1, 10}]
```

Shows intersections of the function with the rectangle based of their common value, so on top and bottom of the rectangle. I need the code to show the intersections based of the common categories, so it should display the green points on left and right sides of the rectangle.

Another question - How can i display the coordinates of the green points next to them?

Comment: does using `MeshFunctions->{#1&} and Mesh -> {{0,3}}` give what you need?

Comment: Yes, works like a charm.
Any idea about the coordinates though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Normal[Plot[f[x, x0, a, n0, c], {x, -.01, 3.01}, 
    Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> Thick,
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]], 
    MeshFunctions -> {Boole[-1 <= #2 <= 1] (# - 1) &}, Mesh -> { {2, -1}},  
    Prolog -> {EdgeForm[{LightBlue, Thick}], Opacity[0.5], LightBlue, 
      Rectangle[{0, -1}, {3, 1}]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-6, 6}}] ]  /. 
  Point[x_] :> {Point[x], Text[Style[Round[x, .1], 16, Black], x + {0, .6}]}, 
{{x0, 2.25}, 0, 10}, {{a, -.3}, -1, 1}, {{n0, 1}, 1, 2}, {{c, 0.9}, 0.1, 10}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can inject the intersection points and labels inside `Prolog`

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, x0, a, n0, c], {x,0, 3.}, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
  Prolog -> {EdgeForm[{LightBlue, Thick}], Opacity[0.5], LightBlue, 
   Rectangle[{0, -1}, {3, 1}], 
  {Green, PointSize[Large], Point@#, Opacity[1], Black, 
  Text[Style[Round[#, .1], 16], # + {0, .5}]} & /@ ({#, f[#, x0, a, n0, c]} & /@ {0, 3})},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-6, 6}}], 
 {{x0, 2.25}, 0, 10}, {{a, -.3}, -1, 1}, {{n0, 1}, 1, 2}, {{c, 0.9}, 0.1, 10}]
```

> same picture

**Note: Why not simply `MeshFunctions -> {# &}` and `Mesh -> { {3, 0}}`?**

To avoid results like this:

[image]